# How do we identify inline xml element when we flow content as story element in inDesign for applying paragraph/Character styling as of required?

Tags: xml, adobe-indesign

We have an indesign Document(.indd) in which we have several master spreads and we need to import a xml and place the content in the respective master spreads .Following is the sample of the xml which we are importing:-

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DOCS>
    <texto>
        <p_pri>La flexibilidad laboral es un tema recurrente en las últimas décadas, como camino a seguir, junto con la seguridad en el empleo, para resolver los problemas acuciantes de las relaciones laborales. Hace ya algún tiempo que un sector doctrinal afirmaba que había que «encontrar la dosis justa, el punto medio entre flexibilidad y rigidez, entre paternalismo social y eficacia económica»@footnotes_begin@vid. <autor>Sagardoy hgfhfg</autor>, J. A.: «Hacia una concepción positiva...», op. cit., p. 287.  J. A.: «Hacia una concepción positiva de la flexibilidad laboral», en AA.VV.: <en-origen_cursiva>Estudios ofrecidos por los catedráticos españoles de Derecho del Trabajo al profesor Manuel Alonso Olea,</en-origen_cursiva> MTSS, Madrid, 1990, p. 267.@footnotes_end@.</p_pri>
    </texto>
</DOCS>`

Here we are trying to apply character styling on autor tags which we are not able to do so.Please find the script :

```
        var pageWidth = null;
        var pageHeight = null;
        var contentArray =[];
        var txf = null;
        var baseParagraphStyle = "";
        main();
        function main(){

                        app.scriptPreferences.userInteractionLevel= UserInteractionLevels.neverInteract; 
                    document = app.open(File("D:/TestImmediate/styleImplementation.indd"));
                    with(document){
                       importXML("D:/TestImmediate/TestStyle.xml");
                       var m_rootElement = document.xmlElements.item(0);
                       }
                var pageCount = 0;
                var m_xmlElement = m_rootElement;
                pageHeight = document.documentPreferences.pageHeight;
                pageWidth = document.documentPreferences.pageWidth;
                populateArray(m_rootElement);
                 processRoot(contentArray);
                }        
         function processRoot(contentArray){
            txf = document.pages.item(document.pages.length-1).textFrames.add({geometricBounds:[5,4,pageHeight,pageWidth]});
             story = txf.parentStory;   
                 for (var i = 0; i < contentArray.length; i++)
                {  if(contentArray[i].markupTag.name.toLowerCase() == "p_pri"){
                         story.insertionPoints[-1].pointSize = 12;
                         story.insertionPoints[-1].contents = contentArray[i].contents;
                         contentArray[i].xmlElements.itemByName("autor").texts.item(0).applyCharacterStyle(document.characterStyles.item("autor"));
                }
             }

         }
        function populateArray(m_rootElement){
                var m_xmlElement = m_rootElement;
                if(m_rootElement.markupTag.name.toLowerCase() == "p_pri"){
                 var len = m_rootElement.xmlElements.length;
                    contentArray.push(m_rootElement);
                    }
                      for (var m_element = 0; m_element < m_xmlElement.xmlElements.length; m_element++ ){   
                       var m_xmlChildElement = m_xmlElement.xmlElements.item(m_element);
                     populateArray (m_xmlChildElement);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating stuff here. You can easily add styles while injecting the XML by using aid:pstyle and aid:cstyle attributes (beware of adding aid namespaces).

You can also add styles at a further stage either through the UI (map styles to tags) or through a script. For the latter, you can simply use xmlExportmaps rather than playing with characters.